# Check if any value in array is equal to current value added to array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array initialized to `Storage[100][3]`.

I insert a group values to each row of the array and move on to the next row and do the same, 
for example:

1 1 3

2 5 6

3 1 3

(keeps going on to 100 rows)

After completing the insertion of 1 entire row I want to check if the values in this current insertion's column's 2 and 3 match the values in all the previous row's, column's 2 and 3.

for example in the above data set I look at column's 2 and 3 in each row and see that rows 1 and 3 have the same values in those columns.

I wrote a program that can compare the current insertion to the previous insertion. But I want to compare the current insertion with all the insertions in the array.

```
const int col=0;

//inserting the values//
for (int row= 0; row < 100; row++) {
    storage[row][col] = t;
    storage[row][col += 1] = xi;
    storage[row][col += 2] = yi;
}

//trying to check if the values are same. need help here//
for (int row = 0; row < 100; row++) {
    if (storage[row][col + 1]==storage[row + 1][col + 1] 
        && storage[row][col + 2] == storage[row + 1][col + 2]) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int row = 1; row < 100; row++) {
    for (int prevRow = 0; prevRow < row; prevRow++) {
        if (storage[row][1] == storage[prevRow][1]
            && storage[row][2] == storage[prevRow][2]) {

            // do something...

        }
    }
}
```

Outer loop starts from `row = 1` becuase row 0 doesn't have previous rows to compare.

Comment: Thanks! So this basically start from the first row and searches for the values until the last row right?

Comment: Yes, the outer for loop is from `row = 1` to `row = 99`. For each `row`, `prevRow` is from `0` to `row - 1`.

Comment: That's awesome, I don't know why I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an algorithm that scales nicely O(log2n) rather than O(n^2) try using a Hash table to keep track of encountered numbers.  My example numbers for the first iteration are 4, 2, 3.
You can get a count of how many times you've encountered your duplicate numbers and most importantly you **don't have to do the heavy lifting of loop-searching yourself**!

```
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
   std::map<int, int> twoColsCounts;
   int storage[100][3];

   int ordinal1 = 4;
   int ordinal2 = 2;
   int ordinal3 = 3;

   for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
   {
      storage[i][0] = ordinal1;
      storage[i][1] = ordinal2;
      storage[i][2] = ordinal3;

      int lastTwoDigits = ordinal2 * 10 + ordinal3;

      auto inMapRecord = twoColsCounts.find(lastTwoDigits);
      if (inMapRecord != twoColsCounts.end())
      {
         // Number Already Found.  Increment count for posterity!
         twoColsCounts[lastTwoDigits]++;
      }
      else
      {
         // Not already encountered - Add it to record with count of 1
         twoColsCounts[lastTwoDigits] = 1;
      }
   }

    Console::WriteLine(L"Done 'big data' style!");
    return 0;
}
```

Good luck!